# Is there a way to pass destination object to ForAllMembers method of AutoMapperProfile object

Tags: c#, automapper

I am just learning how to use AutoMapper utility.

Below is my `AutoMapperProfile` class. Here is how I call my mapper to map `model` object to `user` object:

`var user = _mapper.Map<User>(model);`

I would like to initialize my destination object(`user`) with some properties before calling `var user = _mapper.Map<User>(model);`. Then I would like to call the mapper `var user = _mapper.Map<User>(model);` and pass the user object to the `ForAllMembers` (from the code below - see `AutoMapperProfile`) and preserve those initialized properties during mapping process. The problem I have is that when `ForAllMembers` is called my destination object has all properties set to null initially. Is there a way to pass that object to `ForAllMembers` t?

```
using AutoMapper;
using coreapi.requests;

namespace WebApi.Helpers
{
    public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        // mappings between model and entity objects
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<UserRequest, User>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Blah, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Test))
            .ForAllMembers(x => x.Condition(
                    (src, dest, prop) =>
                    {
                        // ignore null role
                        if (x.DestinationMember.Name == "Blah" && src.Test == null) 
                            return false;

                        return true;
                    }
                ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return !(x.DestinationMember.Name == "Blah" && src.Test == null);`

Comment: The destination object has all properties set to null - that seems to be the problem

Comment: Maybe try `AfterMap`?